# PHP read file to fill variable

Tags: php, html

trying to figure out how to display two value, in this case hour and minutes (hh:mm), from txt to html:
I need to display this two value divided by : in two separate form, if i try with a custom value `$myfile = "10:24";`it work, but if try to read the file, im unable to use explode to get it into array of elements without :.
May ask help?

Thanks
Gian

This is my php above the html page:

```
<?php
#$myfile = "10:24";
#$myfile = file_get_contents("incoming/showtime.txt");
#$myfile = fopen("incoming/showtime.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
#$elements = fread($myfile,filesize("incoming/showtime.txt"));

$myfile = fopen("incoming/showtime.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
$elements= fread($myfile,filesize("incoming/showtime.txt"));
echo $elements;
$str_arr = explode (":", $elements); 
fclose($myfile);
#fclose($myfile);

#$str_arr[0] = 10;
?>
```

HTML FORM:

```
   <td> <input type="number" id="fname" name="hour" value="<?php echo $str_arr[0]; ?>"></td>
    <td> <input type="number" id="lname" name="minute" value="<?php echo $str_arr[1]; ?>"></td>
```

Comment: You could use ``var_dump($str_arr);`` to see if it contains what you intend.

Comment: It seems to be unable to read the second value: array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "19" [1]=> string(1) " " }

Comment: Any suggestion?

Comment: Where is this value 19 coming from? Please tell us the exact contents of `showtime.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $file = 'incoming/showtime.txt';  
  $x = $y = file_get_contents($file);  

  $x = (explode(':',$x));  
  echo $x[0];  

  $y = substr($y,0,2);    
  echo "$y<hr>";
```

[substr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

```
echo"<label><input type='number' id='fname' name='hour' value='$x[0]'> Your \$x[0] = $x[0] and \$y = $y </label>";
```

If `echo` doesn't work  - always check the path and file name against misspelling.